# Python: reordering a string(list) based on a previous list order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am stumped, any help would be great, this is way above my pay grade:

I have string of key values which when identified are provided a number. To make matters more complicated is that they are identified as either an int or string.

The objective is that when a new string is processed, it should use the original key order that might have been previously defined. Additionally the value could always be different

Here is an example of the information gained from the first string:

```
import re
int_dict = {}
string_dict = {}
int_number = 1
string_number = 1
firstlist = "key_a=apples key_z=4 key_e=pears key_b=bananas key_r=3"
re_result = re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\w+)', firstlist)
for i in re_result:
   if i[1].isdigit():
        int_dict[int_number] = i[0]
        int_number += 1
   else:
        string_dict[string_number] = i[0]
        string_number += 1

print int_dict
>>> {1: 'key_z', 2: 'key_r'}
print string_dict
>>> {1: 'key_a', 2: 'key_e', 3: 'key_b'}
```

The second line could be as follows:

```
secondstring = "key_r=54 key_a=grapes key_b=nuts key_z=7 key_r=22"
```

I would like the string re-ordered based on the previous string, in the second string there is also a new key which should just take the next increment based on if its a int or string:

```
secondstring_reordered = "key_a=grapes key_z=7 key_b=nuts key_r=22 key_z=7"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by performing this operation?

Comment: A pattern database which builds knowledge of previous unknown keys and whereby if the key is common, it will always be placed into the correct column in the database regardless of its location in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the first string create a dictionary first, where the key is the key from the string and value is the index of that item in the list returned by `firstlist.split()`

```
>>> d = {item.split('=', 1)[0]:i for i, item in enumerate(firstlist.split())}
>>> d
{'key_e': 2, 'key_b': 3, 'key_a': 0, 'key_r': 4, 'key_z': 1}
```

Now using this dictionary you can sort the list returned by `secondstring.split()`, and then join it back using `str.join`:

```
>>> ' '.join(sorted((item for item in secondstring.split()),
                                                 key=lambda x:d[x.split('=',1)[0]]))
'key_a=grapes key_z=7 key_b=nuts key_r=54 key_r=22'
```

---

If you're sure that the values in the string will never contain a `=` then you can change `item.split('=', 1)` and `x.split('=',1)[0]`  to `item.split('=')[1]` and `x.split('=')[1]` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works in principle but it does not take into account new keys that might be introduced into the second string. Additionally, does it take into account the fact that they key might be int or string?

Comment: @dtalbot If the second string contains keys that might not be present in the first string, then use `lambda x:d.get(x.split('=',1)[0], default_value)` as key during sorting, where `default_value` can be any value that you want to use for comparison.

Comment: So what you are saying, is that the default_value in this case is the new value introduced? How would I write it exactly?

Comment: @dtalbot That depends on you, if use type in 100 there then 100 will be used to compare that missing key with other keys.

Comment: @dtalbot Please provide better examples in the question body.